# Spring's Annotation Type Required deprecation

Tags: java, spring, deprecated

Spring's [Annotation Type Required](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Required.html) is marked as deprecated

> **Deprecated.**
> as of 5.1, in favor of using constructor injection for required settings (or a custom InitializingBean implementation)

Same for relevant [RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html)

But it's not clear what's the replacement, it seems that it should be unavailable.

Is this change prevent us marking method as required unless it's part of constructor method ? to prevent unexpected exceptions on class creation ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are three ways to inject a bean via annotation:

**Field injection**

```
@Autowired
private FooService fooService;
```

**Setter injection**

```
private FooService fooService;

@Autowired
public void setFooService(FooService fooService) {
    this.fooService = fooService
}
```

**Constructor injection** (this is the mentioned replacement)

```
private final FooService fooService;

@Autowired
public MyComponent(FooService fooService) {
    this.fooService = fooService;
}
```

As you can see, the only way to declare your Service `final` is by using the constructor injection, which replaces the `@Required` annotation because it forces the user of your class to instantiate it with the required services. The user does not have to be Spring, it could be a simple unit test as well.

You should use constructor injection for mandatory dependencies and setter injections for optional dependencies instead of field injection. 
Some reasons why:

- It makes it clear to everybody which dependencies are required
- It makes testing easier
- You can make your objects immutable

Further reading:

- http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/
- https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/
- https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/

**Update: non-annotated constructor injection**

As one commentator was wondering about a `final` field annotated with `@Autowired` while the constructor was not annotated:

> If a class only declares a single constructor to begin with, it will always be used, even if not annotated.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html ("Autowired Constructors")

But even though it is not necessary to annotate the constructor in this case, I would still do it: it documents the code and if anyone will ever add another (non-annotated) constructor, the code will still work.

Comment: I made my user DAO marked final working although injected through field in registration service. 
Constructor needs to exist.
 Does that provide a dirty way to achieve the same functionality as with annotation Autowired on constructor in the end?

Comment: @user3625699 if your class has only one constructor, Spring will always use it, even if it is not annotated with `@Autowired`. So, actually you're using constructor injection and annotating the field is pointless (or could even be misleading). I advise you to annotate your constructor with `@Autowired` even though Spring does not require you to do so. It documents your intention and if you or somebody else adds another (non-annotated) constructor, the code will still work

Comment: I know this question is quite old but I just came across a piece of code which could be useful to what I'm working on. It has Required annotation in a non Spring managed Bean. If I replace that with constructor injection with @Autowired, I get warnings saying it must be used within a Spring managed bean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it is deprecated but still you can use it by mentioning below in xml file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Comment: I asked for replacement, so your answer is irrelevant here